# Select table entries belonging to combinations of entries in another table (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Regarding MySQL queries, how can I get all table entries that belong to combinations of entries in another table?

*Background:* I would like to count orders which consist of order items. Each order item has a state like 'canceled' or 'delivered'. There are partial deliveries, so that there can be both delivered and canceled orders in one order. I would like to count the net orders and I would like to know how many orders have items with more than one item status.

```
Order Number |  Order Item  |   Status

X0001        |  Item        |   delivered
X0001        |  Item        |   delivered
X0002        |  Item        |   delivered
X0002        |  Item        |   canceled
X0002        |  Item        |   delivered
X0003        |  Item        |   delivered
```

I have 3 valid orders here and one order with delivered/canceled. How can I ask for all orders which have at least one delivered and one canceled item?

As I am very new to MySQL I am basically looking for the right approach. Do I need subqueries or joints for this?

Edit: First of all, sorry for the late reply. And sorry again because my question was obviously misleading.

There are three tables involved: 'order', 'order_item' and 'order_item_status'.

'order' and 'order_item' are linked through 'order_item.fk_order' and 'order.id_order'.

'order_item' and 'order_item_status' are linked through 'order_item.fk_order_item_status' and 'order_item_status.id_order_item_status'.

You have been very helpful so far but I am still a bit stuck as I do not know how to finally count by combination. 
The perfect result would be something like that:

```
{shipped}            |  34
{canceled}           |  12
{shipped, canceled}  |  8
{closed, canceled}   |  4
{closed}             |  27
...                  |  ...
```

But I don't know how to deal with combinations in a query. Maybe you have some more helpful hints for me ...

Thank you very much.

Comment: What would the result be for given data?

Comment: WHERE a IN (x,y) GROUP BY b HAVING COUNT(*) = no. of items in IN clause

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two table:
orders (list of your orders)
order_items (list of itemd of order)
two table are relationed by field fk_order.

try this:

```
SELECT o.id, (select count(*) from order_items i where i.status = 'delivered' and i.fk_order = o.id) as item_delivered, (select count(distinct i.status) from order_items i where i.fk_order = o.id) as status_no
FROM orders o
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data are all in one table like you described. Then you want to group your data by order number and then only get the orders with both canceled and delivered ?
The request should also look like :

```
select * from table \
group by Order Number \
Having State="canceled" and State="delivered"
```

Answer (score 0):

By join on the table with the same table you can select rows with different values. Then count the distinct order numbers.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orig.Number)
FROM order_items AS orig
INNER JOIN order_items AS diff ON diff.Number = orig.Number AND diff.Status != orig.Status
```

This is quicker than using sub-queries.

Edit: Forgot to mention it's a more scalable implementation as well as you can add more order statuses without this failing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are talking about "combinations of entries in another table" ?
According to the following of your question you have one single table with - at least - 3 attributes: Order number, Order item, Status. Is that correct or are some of those attributes in another table and in that case can you elaborate ?

Otherwise I would try to use sub-requests and do something like:

SELECT T1.* FROM table T1 WHERE T1.status=canceled AND T1.order_number IN (SELECT T2.order_number FROM table T2 where T2.status=delivered)